# Keeping track (count) of the videos I've watched in YouTube

Tags: web-browser, youtube

Is there *any* add-on in *any* browser (or even a separate software/application) that can count the number of times I've watched a video in YouTube?

For example I want to know that I have viewed *that* certain video 13 times during last month.

Possible output:

```
February 2014
Shakira - Can't Remember to Forget You ft. Rihanna (shakiraVEVO) 14 views
Lady Gaga - Bad Romance (LadyGagaVEVO) 12 views
etc.
```

A more demanding option would be to know the time spent on each video (because a video could last 1 hour but I could have spent just 20 minutes in 4 views cause of jumping forward or viewing a specific part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free web browser history examiner utility which could be used to generate the information that you need, it is available [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html).

Since it can export the information to a number of formats it should let you generate the view counts periodically - N.B. Internet Explorer is notorious for giving inflated counts of the number of visits.

To quote the web page:

> New Web browser history viewer
>
> BrowsingHistoryView is a new utility
> that reads the history data of 4 different Web browsers (Internet
> Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, and Safari) and displays the
> browsing history of all these Web browsers in one table. The browsing
> history table includes the following information: Visited URL, Title,
> Visit Time, Visit Count, Web browser and User Profile.
> BrowsingHistoryView allows you to watch the browsing history of all
> user profiles in a running system, as well as to get the browsing
> history from external hard drive. You can also export the browsing
> history into csv/tab-delimited/html/xml file from the user interface,
> or from command-line, without displaying any user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Now, there is a plugin to Firefox that does exactly what you ask for:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/yt-stats/

Answer (score -1):

YouTube keeps track of what you watched and what not. 
You can get your history on YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/feed/history.
You would obviously need a Google Account for this.

Comment: This is nice. But my main point is not WHICH videos i have watched, but HOW MANY TIMES i have watched each video.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. We want answers that explain how the recommended product matches the requirements and fits the purpose of the question. See [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/214) for tips on writing an answer. If you'd done that, you might have realized that your answer does not fulfill the requirements, which is to show a **count** of the number of times.